# FastAPI how to print the HTTP request status code

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests, fastapi, uvicorn, starlette

I am new to FastAPI framework, I want to print out the response status code from a PUT request.

```
@app.put('/user/{id}', status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK) 
async def processing(id: str, request: Request, response: Response):
    data = await request.json()
    status = response.status_code
    print(status_code)
    logger.info("Got response [%s]", status)
    return data
```

The status returned is 'None'. But uvicorn server shows a 200 OK status. How can I include this code in my logging/print out?

Thanks.

Comment: The `status_code` from the decorator won't be set until you've returned from your function. Since you're inside the function handling the request itself, don't you know if everything went OK or not?

Comment: @MatsLindh thanks for helping. The server (uvicorn) does indicate response status in Terminal, but I wanted to code an if/else condition depending on the status_code returned. How could I do this?

Comment: You're the one setting the status code - which status code do you want to intercept? The view function - the one you've included - configures its own status code, either through `response.status_code` or through the `status_code` parameter on the decorator. If you want to intercept internal status codes (4xx, 5xx) that your code doesn't generate by itself a middleware might be what you want, not a view endpoint.

Comment: @MatsLindh Thanks for clarifying this, will try implement a middleware to intercept status codes generated by http calls from another server.